# Pipe html to open command, or similar

Tags: html, browser

I can open (and properly display) an html file with a browser using

```
open "/Users/fame/foo.html"
```

but is there a way to do something like this:

```
echo "<body> foo </body>" | open
```

I am looking to avoid saving temp files to the filesystem. The second open command (obviously) does not work.

Comment: here is one example, but it requires installing something: https://gist.github.com/defunkt/318247

Comment: this too: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24931/how-to-make-firefox-read-stdin